# Expected CHAR got NUMBER

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

DB: Oracle 11g

Query:

```
SELECT CASE
      WHEN rs.OPTION = '3'
      THEN
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ex.EXTS) AS TMPCOL0
        FROM CRSIDM.SUB_OPTS ex
        INNER JOIN CRSIDM.SUB_OPTS_GRP cg
        ON  cg.GROUP_ID   = ex.GRP_ID        
        )
      ELSE
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ex.EXTS) AS TMPCOL0
        FROM CRSIDM.SUB_OPTS ex
        INNER JOIN CRSIDM.SUB_OPTS_POL cg
        ON  cg.GROUP_ID   = ex.GRP_ID
        )
    END    AS PROPTS
  FROM PR_OPTS
```

I am getting error 'expected CHAR got NUMBER', here EXTS,GROUP_ID & GRP_ID are numeric. Then how there is a chance of expecting CHAR?

Comment: Is `rs` an alias for `PR_OPTS`, or is there a join you aren't showing? What data type is `OPTION` - and is that enclosed in double-quoutes in your actual code, since it's a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/ap_keywd001.htm), or really called something else?

Answer (score 1):

Generally when Oracle compares different datatypes such as a NUMBER with a CHARACTER, implicit conversion kicks in and all is well (provided the data can be converted.) For example, if you have a function that expects a CHARACTER value but you pass it a NUMBER, all is well - Oracle simply converts the NUMBER to character.

E.g. a function like this:

```
create or replace function get_something(p_id VARCHAR2) return number ...
```

works if you call it with this:

```
get_dno(10);
```

or this:

```
get_dno('10');
```

and in SQL:

```
select * from some_table where numeric_column = '10' -- no problem.
```

A popular place where you see this kind of error is with the return values in CASE statements. For instance, you'll get that error if you have something like this:

```
SQL> SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN '1' ELSE 2 END
  2  FROM dual
  3  ;
SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN '1' ELSE 2 END
                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
```

(The datatype from the first WHEN clause is what it expects in the other WHEN/ELSE clauses that follow.)

But in your case the WHEN and THEN both return counts - the datatypes are consistent. So, I think you have a red-herring in there.

As Alex mentioned above, OPTION is a keyword and if you try and create a table with that as a column name, Oracle disagrees:

```
SQL> create table dummy
  2  (option varchar2(10)
  3  );
(option varchar2(10)
 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

This works:

```
SQL> create table dummy
  2  (option_col varchar2(10)
  3  );

Table created.
```

or you could do it with quotes:

```
SQL> create table dummy
  2  ("option" varchar2(10));

Table created.
```

But now you're in a world of hurt - you need quotes from now on:

```
SQL> select option from dummy;
select option from dummy
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression

SQL> select d.option from dummy d;
select d.option from dummy d
         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

With quotes:

```
SQL> select d."option" from dummy d;

no rows selected
```

So, if your query is really giving you "expected CHAR, got NUMBER", it looks to me like something is off.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, it means some of the fields you are using aren't compatible with each other.  It's basically a "type mismatch".  Just check to see if any types of CHAR are being used with types of NUMBER.  Then you can either switch the type of one, or simply use a conversion as part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `OPTION = '3'`, the quotation marks indicate that you're looking for a string containing the solitary character `3`.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN rs.OPTION = 3 
    THEN 
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ex.EXTS) AS TMPCOL0 
        FROM CRSIDM.SUB_OPTS ex 
        INNER JOIN CRSIDM.SUB_OPTS_GRP cg 
        ON cg.GROUP_ID = ex.GRP_ID)
    ELSE
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ex.EXTS) AS TMPCOL0
        FROM CRSIDM.SUB_OPTS ex
        INNER JOIN CRSIDM.SUB_OPTS_POL cg
        ON cg.GROUP_ID = ex.GRP_ID)
    END AS PROPTS
FROM PR_OPTS
```